# How can I find which AuthenticationProvider/Filter failed in my SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

(I am using Spring Boot 1.3.5 and Spring Security 4.2.2).

I have multiple custom `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`s and  `AuthenticationProvider`s in my application, and they each can throw different types of exceptions that all should result in a failed authentication. So I wrote a class which implements `AuthenticationFailureHandler` and implements

```
onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, 
    HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
```

to listen for failed authentication attempts.

My question - is it possible within my `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` to know which `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` failed? I'm able to get the specific exception that was thrown since the last parameter is `AuthenticationException`, but I also need to know the `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` that failed to determine how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it work to wire a separate instance of `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` for each filter? It might be simpler than one handler that knows everything, e.g.:

```
MyFirstFilter first = new MyFirstFilter();
first.setAuthenticationFailureHandler
    (new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler(...));
MySecondFilter second = ...

http
    .addFilter(first) ...
```

If not, you could possibly write something to the `request` object.

Instead of extending `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`, it might work to instead just extend `OncePerRequestFilter`, which may give you a flexibility that the AAPF template doesn't give you.